# PHP store an anonymous function in an array (class context)

Tags: php, arrays, function, class, anonymous

I know it's possible to store an anonymous function as an array value in PHP, but why does it return NULL in class context?

```
class firstClass {

    public static $functions = array();

    function __construct()
    {

        self::$functions += array( "echo" => function( $text ) { echo $text; }, "fruit" => "apple" );

    }

}

class secondClass {

    function __construct()
    {

        var_dump( firstClass::$functions ); // returns array(1){ ["fruit"] => string(5) => "apple" )
        var_dump( firstClass::$functions["echo"] ); // returns NULL

    }

}


$class = new firstClass;
```

Comment: The constructor of the first class is never called.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's funny that you are getting NULL — when I test your code, I get the expected result (i.e. not NULL).
Try the following code, maybe this could work: (if not, try upgrading your PHP version?)

```
// ----------------------------------------------------
// First try with a simple array, outside a class
// ----------------------------------------------------

$test_array = array(
    "string" => "some string" ,
    "function" => function() {
        echo 'i am an anonymous function outside a Class';
    }
);

var_dump($test_array);



// ----------------------------------------------------
// Now try in a Class context
// ----------------------------------------------------

class classContext {

    public static $functions = array();

    public function __construct() {
        self::$functions += array(
            "string" => "some string in classContext" ,
            "function" => function() {
                echo 'i am an anonymous function inside a Class';
            }
        );
    }

}

class secondClass {

    public function __construct() {
        var_dump(classContext::$functions);
        var_dump(classContext::$functions['function']);
    }
}

new classContext;
new secondClass;
```

The result should be as follows:

```
array(2) {
    ["string"]=>
      string(11) "some string"

    ["function"]=>
      object(Closure)#1 (0) {}
}

array(2) {
    ["string"]=>
      string(27) "some string in classContext"

    ["function"]=>
      object(Closure)#3 (1) {
          ["this"]=> object(classContext)#2 (0) {}
      }
}

object(Closure)#3 (1) {
    ["this"]=> object(classContext)#2 (0) {}
}
```

Comment: my pleasure @Ralph :)

Answer (score 1):

firstClass constructor never call, you use a static variable

Comment: I forgot to add the initalisation, sorry. But a normal value does work, it is very strange..